# Add a link between two children in d3.js force graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have to make force graph using d3.js where I have to show different links. The current version works fine.

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");
root = {
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [{
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [{
                "name": "cluster",
                "children": [{
                        "name": "A",
                        "size": 50000
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B",
                        "size": 50000
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "C",
                        "size": 50000
                    },
                ],
                "size": 50000

            },
            {
                "name": "graph",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "E",
                    "size": 50000
                }, ]
            },
            {
                "name": "optimization",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
                    "size": 50000
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}

update()

function update() {
    var nodes = [...flatten(root)];
    let links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

    // Update links.
    link = link.data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    link.exit().remove();

    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();
    node = node.data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });

    node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5;
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        });

    node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
        :
        d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
        :
        "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

function addLink(idSrc, idTarget) {
    var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
    links.push({
        source: nodes.find(x => x.name === idSrc),
        target: nodes.find(x => x.name === idTarget)
    });
    force.start();
    update();
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```

```css
.node circle {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: #3182bd;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        pointer-events: none;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }

    line.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #9ecae1;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="node"></div>
```

See the above code. 'A' and 'B' are two children and I want them to be connect with link. I don't want any collapsing between them only want a line.

For that purpose I have create addLink function which takes names of two nodes are create a link object and add it links array and then update the graph. But its not working. I am not a d3 expert. Obviously I am missing something very simple.

I think code in in answer of [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBVzWo?editors=0010) post is somewhat relevant but I can't  get it right.